# Iterate through a list in VF page using PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, repeat

In my Visual force page I have a code which displays the elements of a list:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >

       <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
```

In controller:

```
   public List<Skill_Review__c> getSkillReview() {

        skillReview=new List<skillReview>();
        List<Skill_Review__c> results = [SELECT Id,Name,Skill__c,Level__c FROM Skill_Review__c where Interview__c =:review.id ];

        return results;

    }
```

But this displays only the first element of the list(SkillReview), how can I display all the elements of the list in my VF page. I saw the  tag which I guess iterate through a list, but how do I use it here in PageBlockTable?

Comment: your question is not clear? If you want to access other fields then use `{!sobject.fieldName}`

Comment: can you post your class which contains SkillReview ?

Comment: Please see the edit now. I am returning a skill review object list as result in my controller extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access all fields in vf page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{! SkillReview }" var="ct" >
       <apex:column value="{! ct.Skill__c}"/>
       <apex:column value="{! ct.Name}"/>
       <apex:column value="{! ct.Level__c }"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable >
```

If fields doesn't display on page. then check you field security setting that should be read only.. goto-object--field--click on the field--click on above security button now update security to readonly

Comment: Does this give me each Skill_c from the SkillReview list variable? I use the same code as above and I only see one skill on my page.

Comment: @Rdvsm Yes it will display all 3 fields in VF page. If doesn't then check you field security setting that should be read only.. goto-object--field--click on the field--click on above security button now update security to readonly